# WebApi controller fails - thread culture issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a controller method that fails on the return statement

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public UserModel Get(int id)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");

    BP.DataAccess.DataUtilities.DatabaseCommand.ConnectionString =
        _configuration["connectionStrings:PrimaryConnection"];

    UserModel user = UserService.GetUserById(id);

    return user;
}
```

The `UserModel` class has:

```
public int RoleTypeId { get; set; }
private ListModels.RoleTypeModel _RoleType;
public ListModels.RoleTypeModel RoleType
{
    get
    {
        _RoleType = Trisura.BP.Core.ListServices
            .RoleTypeService.GetRoleTypeById(RoleTypeId);
        return _RoleType;
    }
    private set { _RoleType = value; }
}

public static RoleTypeModel GetRoleTypeById(int id)
{
    int cultureId = CultureService.GetThreadCultureId();

    List<ListModels.RoleTypeModel> localizedList =
        GetRoleTypesLocalizedList(cultureId);

    ListModels.RoleTypeModel roleTypeModel =
        localizedList.Where(roletype => roletype.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (roleTypeModel == null)
    {
        throw new CoreExceptions.ObjectNotFoundInDatabaseException(
            string.Format("The requested role type (ID = {0}) was not found.", id));
    }

    return roleTypeModel;
}

public static RoleTypeModel GetRoleTypeById(int id)
{
    // this returns "en-US" (0)  instead of "en-CA" (1)
    int cultureId = CultureService.GetThreadCultureId(); 

    List<ListModels.RoleTypeModel> localizedList = GetRoleTypesLocalizedList(cultureId);
    ListModels.RoleTypeModel roleTypeModel =
        localizedList.Where(roletype => roletype.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (roleTypeModel == null)
    {
        throw new CoreExceptions.ObjectNotFoundInDatabaseException(
            string.Format("The requested role type (ID = {0}) was not found.", id));
            
        return roleTypeModel;
    }
}
```

when the controller hits `return user;`, it fails because the thread `CurrentCulture` is set to `en-US` even I explicitly said that culture is `en-CA`.

Does anyone have an explanation? Does this happen in a separate thread?

How to ensure that my model will run with the same culture?

Comment: If its a Web Api controller, you should return IHttpActionResult as method return type, and wrap it like **return Ok(model)**,
If it's MVC controller u should return **ActionResult** and also wrap it again.

Comment: its an web api controller but there is no issue with controller per se. i think the problem is with json serializer. on that line where it returns model it first needs to serialize it. so it seems that serializerdoes not run in the same thread.

Comment: It may not be your problem here but @narekye is spot on, you should be returning `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: Are you looking to change the default culture for the app to `en-CA` or just a single request?

Comment: for the single request. since I don't know user culture in advance - just after login. 
not sure that i understand that i should return IHttpActionResult instead model. this is get request so it should return model as JSON. rigth?